# How to ajax reload partial from partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, partials

I have an app in which I different networks have messages.

In my network show view I display all the messages in with a partial "overview" which shows a link to the message content. The content of the messages is loaded with ajax inside #detailed div:

```
<div class="span2" id="sidebar">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/sidebar' %> 
</div>

<div class="span4" id="overview">
    <%= render :partial => 'overview' %>
</div>

<div class="span6" id="detailed">
    <%= render :partial => 'nothing' %>
</div>
```

_overview.html.erb, in which i :

```
<h2>Messages</h2>
UNREAD:
<%= render :partial => 'items', :collection => @task.find_all{|item| item.unread == true }.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse, :as => :item %>
READ:
<%= render :partial => 'items', :collection => @task.find_all{|item| item.unread == false }.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse, :as => :item %>
```

_items.html.erb:

```
<%= div_for item do %>
        <%= link_to(network_message_path(@network, item), :remote => true, :class => ["message item",    ("unread" if item.unread == true)]) do %>...<% end %> 
<% end %>
```

The message is contains a partial again with the full content, comments etc.. Code by which the message is loaded:

```
$("#detailed").hide().html("<%= j(render('show_message', :message => @message)) %>").fadeIn('fast');
```

If someone opens the detailed view, I update the unread status of the message to false. I would like to reload the overview partial, if someone loads the message into the details. One solution would be to just use jQuery to move things around, but the system will become more complicated with more filtering options. Therefor, reloading the overview partial would be a simpler solution. But what would be the fastes way to do so? As I need to reload the show method in the networks controller, alongside loading the show method in the message controller.

What would be the best solution, besides jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a module to load the overview partial with ajax.